# Consistent enumeration of a btattached controller

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez

I have a controller that is attached with btattach
as a systemd service:

```
/usr/bin/btattach -B /dev/ttyACM0 -S 1000000
```

The same command seems to result in different
enumerations. Sometimes its:

```
$ busctl tree org.bluez
└─/org
  └─/org/bluez
    └─/org/bluez/hci1
```

other times:

```
$ busctl tree org.bluez
└─/org
  └─/org/bluez
    └─/org/bluez/hci0
```

Is there a way to have fixed enumeration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The hciX naming is assigned by the kernel and can not be guaranteed.
>   For BR/EDR single mode or BR/EDR/LE dual-mode controller, you can read
>   the property for the Bluetooth Device Address to find and match the
>   controller.

Originally answered by Marcel Holtmann on the bluez mailing lists.